# Georeferencing historic airphotos along constantly-moving section of San Andreas fault?

Tags: georeferencing, topography, aerial-photography, ground-control, agisoft-photoscan

I'm a geology graduate student working on a master's thesis project in which I'm measuring creep (movement) over time along a section of the San Andreas fault (in California, USA) using SfM derived from overlapping historic aerial photos. The airphoto series' I'm using are from various time periods spanning the last ~80 years and none of them are georeferenced. The section of the fault I'm focused on is the creeping section, which means it is constantly slipping - at an average rate of about 30 mm/yr. Because both sides of the fault are always moving (in opposite directions relative to one another), any potential ground control points from one time period will not match spatially with GCPs from any other time period.

The end goal of the project is to compare 3D point clouds (from SfM, using Agisoft Metashape Pro) from each time period to one another for eventual ICP analysis to measure the respective offsets. The only way this can work is if the data from each time period are precisely georeferenced to one another. Because I have no stationary GCPs over time, I am at a loss as to how to accomplish this. Since the data does not necessarily have to be georeferenced to the Earth (although that would be ideal) and only have to be georeferenced to one another, one idea I had was to use GCPs on only one side of the fault; but that seems likely to produce unacceptably high levels of error. I'm also wondering if it may be easier to just produce the point clouds as-is (without any coordinate system) and deal with georeferencing those rather than the airphotos.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Thank you for having taken our [Tour]. I recommend also reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: Could you describe your dataset a little more? Like, e.g., hjow precisous should your georeferencing be, how many pictures do you have, how they relates to each other in space and/or time? What's their resolution? Are they clustered 'in time', e.g. do they form groups that can be considered to have been taken during the same period? Do you also have some DEMs in the time period span you mentioned? Or do you only rely on a modern DEM's, if any? Btw, it seems a nice research project, but it's hard to answer without knowing more.

Comment: You need a GIS software to contain the Longitude and Latitude AND altitude to be able to use Agisoft Photoscan (aka Metashape). I worked a lot of 1938 old aerial photos and use them to input into Metashape.  It can be very overwhelm for you at first but it takes time to understand the software.  You can google it to find information on these that I have found to be helpful